# Dice Probabilities - How often does 3, 4, 5 show up in 5 dice on one roll?

Tags: probability, dice

I want to find out the probability for rolling 5 dice and the result containing at least 3, 4, and 5 without caring what the other 2 numbers are. I'm not very familiar with this kind of probability so I've written a computer program to go through each combination and give me the result. I'd like to know how to do this without doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first determine the probability that at least one of those numbers does *not* show up, and then subtract from one to get the probability that all three *do* show up.

What is the probability that out of five dice, there is no $3$ OR no $4$ OR no $5$?  We might naively begin by assuming that we add up the probability that there's no $3$, the probability that there's no $4$, and the probability that there's no $5$.

However, in doing so, we've duplicated some rolls, in which there is no $3$ AND no $4$.  Similarly for rolls where there is no $3$ AND no $5$, and where there is no $4$ AND no $5$.  So we need to subtract those out.

But now we've subtracted, once too many, the rolls where there is no $3$ AND no $4$ AND no $5$, so we need to add that back in.

$$
\begin{align}
P(\mbox{no 3 OR no 4 OR no 5})
    & = P(\mbox{no 3})+P(\mbox{no 4})+P(\mbox{no 5}) \\
    & - P(\mbox{no 3 AND no 4})-P(\mbox{no 3 AND no 5})-P(\mbox{no 4 AND no 5}) \\
    & + P(\mbox{no 3 AND no 4 AND no 5}) \\
    & = 3(5/6)^5 - 3(2/3)^5 + (1/2)^5 = 1091/1296
\end{align}
$$

so

$$
P(\mbox{3 AND 4 AND 5}) = 205/1296
$$

Comment: Thanks Brian, that matches my result. But I guess what I'm asking is for a bit more verbose of an answer. How did you start with what you started with, and how did you derive the following formula.

Comment: I'll add a bit more exposition to the solution.

Comment: Will that suffice?

Comment: Ok Brian, I'm following along so far.

Comment: I understand what probabilities you want and why. I don't exactly understand how you turn say the - P(no 3 AND no 4) line into -3(2/3)^5

Comment: Ahh, OK, that I'll explain as a comment.  There are six sides on a die, of which two are $3$ and $4$.  The probability that a *single* die comes up with no $3$ AND no $4$ is therefore $4/6$, or $2/3$.  The probability that all five dice come up with no $3$ AND no $4$ is $2/3$ multiplied by itself five times, or $(2/3)^5$.  Finally, along with no $3$ AND no $4$, there is also no $3$ AND no $5$, and finally no $4$ AND no $5$.  So that line, altogether, is $3(2/3)^5$.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! I marked it as correct and when I have enough rep I'll upvote it as well. Appreciate your help!

Comment: You're quite welcome!